# MVC using JTable on the model

Tags: java, database, swing, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a swing application working with a database in MVC but my jtable is empty when the window start when i decided to put a jtable on my model (also the defaulttablemodel) to respect MVC paradigme and now its not working here is my model :

```
public class Model {

private JTable jTable1;
private DefaultTableModel modelTab;
private Database db;

public Model() {
    this.db = new Database();
    jTable1 = new JTable();
    modelTab = new DefaultTableModel();
}
```

controler :

```
 public void updateJTable(){
    JTable jTable1 = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel modelTab = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelTab.addColumn("id");
    modelTab.addColumn("Désignation");
    modelTab.addColumn("Description");
    Database db = model.getDb();
    ResultSet rs = db.SelectFromTableRS("id_designation, intitule_designation, desc_designation", "DESIGNATION");
    String id = "", i = "", d = "";
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            if (!rs.next()) break;
            id = rs.getString("id_designation");
            i = rs.getString("intitule_designation");
            d = rs.getString("desc_designation");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        modelTab.addRow(new Object[]{id, i, d});
    }
    model.setModelTab(modelTab);
    model.setjTable1(jTable1);
}
```

view :

```
    JPanel generalPano = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel centerPan = new JPanel();
    centerPan.add(new JScrollPane(model.getjTable1(),
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));

    generalPano.add(new JScrollPane(model.getjTable1()), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setContentPane(generalPano);
```

actually i just know that view start with an empty jtable but as you can see in my controlGroup, its looking the good way :

```
public class ControlGroup {

private Model model;
private Vue vue;
public ControlButton controlButton;
public ControlText controlText;
public ControlData controlData;
public ControlMouse controlMouse;

public ControlGroup(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
    vue = new Vue(model);
    controlData = new ControlData(model,vue);
    controlButton = new ControlButton(model,vue);
    controlText = new ControlText(model,vue);
    controlMouse = new ControlMouse(model, vue);

    vue.display();
}
```

Comment: *but something wrong* ... isnt something we can help with. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: The JTable belongs to the view (Vue perhaps). The controller sets its table model. Loading a new table model from the database would simply do a jTable.setModel at the end. The table can be created and layout once.

Comment: Yes, thanks Joop Eggen, working perfectly now.

Comment: *"Yes, thanks Joop Eggen.."* Tip: Add @JoopEggen (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Joop: Can you upgrade that to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JTable belongs to the view (Vue perhaps). The controller sets its table model. Loading a new table model from the database would simply do a jTable.setModel at the end.

The table can be created and layout *once*.

Hence no need to always create a new table and replace it in the GUI.